# How do I sorted dict.keys() or dict base on part of individual keys in the dictionary (python)

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I have a `dict.keys()` as shown below:

```py
dict_keys(['[TH03438A] TRIPLE ACTION 175GM Twinpack_MY', 
'[1051931] CTBM TWISTER FH M +CAP 1PK ASIA*72', 
'[1108229] AJAX F'LOSO 2L AB APPLE/EPAL SEGAR (NEW)', 
'[1051987] CTBM TWISTER FH S +CAP 1PK ASIA*72', 
'[1106530] SOFTLAN 2L FLORAL FANTASY (PINK)', 
'TRIPLE ACTION 175GM TWINPACK_MY'])
```

I would like to sort it base on the product name(keys) after some manipulation, by removing the product number if any (eg: `[TH03438A]`) and the space before the product actual name. So the sorted keys should be return as follows:

```py
dict_keys(['[1108229] AJAX F'LOSO 2L AB APPLE/EPAL SEGAR (NEW)', 
'[1051931] CTBM TWISTER FH M +CAP 1PK ASIA*72', 
'[1051987] CTBM TWISTER FH S +CAP 1PK ASIA*72', 
'[1106530] SOFTLAN 2L FLORAL FANTASY (PINK)', 
'TRIPLE ACTION 175GM TWINPACK_MY', 
'[TH03438A] TRIPLE ACTION 175GM Twinpack_MY'])
```

I tried doing it this way:

```py
test = sorted(report_table.keys(), key=lambda k : k.split('] ')[-1])
```

But I think I'm not doing it right; what should be the right argument for key(sort function) so I can access individual dict keys?

Comment: Thanks @APhillips for helping me formatting my post. Looks clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use next solution:
`sorted(report_table.keys(), key=lambda item: item.split(']')[-1].strip())`

An example based on your data:

```
lst = ['[TH03438A] TRIPLE ACTION 175GM Twinpack_MY', '[1051931] CTBM TWISTER FH M +CAP 1PK ASIA*72', "[1108229] AJAX F'LOSO 2L AB APPLE/EPAL SEGAR (NEW)", '[1051987] CTBM TWISTER FH S +CAP 1PK ASIA*72', '[1106530] SOFTLAN 2L FLORAL FANTASY (PINK)', 'TRIPLE ACTION 175GM TWINPACK_MY']
assert sorted(lst, key=lambda item: item.split(']')[-1].strip()) == ['[1108229] AJAX F\'LOSO 2L AB APPLE/EPAL SEGAR (NEW)', '[1051931] CTBM TWISTER FH M +CAP 1PK ASIA*72', '[1051987] CTBM TWISTER FH S +CAP 1PK ASIA*72', '[1106530] SOFTLAN 2L FLORAL FANTASY (PINK)', 'TRIPLE ACTION 175GM TWINPACK_MY', '[TH03438A] TRIPLE ACTION 175GM Twinpack_MY']
```

If you need sort you dictionary you have to do next:

```
import collections

sorted_list = sorted(report_table.items(), key=lambda items: items[0].split('] ')[-1])
sorted_report_table = collections.OrderedDict(sorted_list)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, for both the standard answer and extra info on producing an ordered dict.